# How to delete temporary files on mac

Tags: macos, terminal

How to delete temporary files from mac using terminal.
By temporary I mean files starting with **~$**.
They're shown in terminal but not in finder.

Comment: They may not `temporary`, print it with `ls ~$*` first.

Answer (score 0):

rm is the command for removing files

```
rm ~$*
```

will remove all files starting with ~$